# Stored procedure out parameter returning null

Tags: java, stored-procedures, jdbc, callable-statement

I've got a stored procedure, and I'm calling it using the standard syntax (I say that, but I've never called a procedure before).

The stored procedure, when called through Toad or SQLDeveloper, it does return the correct value (which is a number). The stored procedure pulls data from one table and inserts it into another. The procedure does work, and is working when I call it, it's simply not returning the correct value.

However, when I use the below code, I get 0 when using getInt (which is the equivalent of null):

```
    String testCallable = "{call PKG_RING_EDIT_CORE_TABLES.move_core_to_preload(?,?)}";
    cstmt = con.prepareCall(testCallable);
    cstmt.setInt(1, 196);
    cstmt.registerOutParameter(2, oracle.jdbc.OracleTypes.NUMBER);

    Integer rows = cstmt.executeUpdate();

    System.out.println("Rows affected " + rows);

    Integer resultingId = cstmt.getInt(2);

    System.out.println("Pulled record from core table. New pre_record_load_id = " + resultingId);
```

If anyone could give me any guidance as to why this is returning null, then it would be greatly appreciated. I appreciate it may be difficult without seeing the procedure code (it's rather long, so am not posting it), however any guidance is great.

Thanks.

**Edit:**

Here is the declaration of the procedure:

```
procedure move_core_to_preload (p_encounter_id_i_nr in encounters.encounter_id%type
  , p_pre_rec_ld_id_o_nr out pre_record_load.pre_record_load_id%type)
```

Here is the section that returns the value from the proecure:

```
  p_pre_rec_ld_id_o_nr := lv_PRE_RECORD_LOAD_ID_nr;  -- pass out PK id for inserted record
```

Comment: Is the stored procedure on an Oracle DB?  What does `wasNull()` return?  Please show the parts of the procedure that are relevant to that second parameter.

Comment: @rgettman Yes, it is an OracleDB. wasNull() returns true. Will edit question to show the section of the procedure. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for showing more code and more information.  But it's not quite enough information.  However, from this code I can tell that either `lv_PRE_RECORD_LOAD_ID_nr` is `NULL` or that the assignment statement was not executed.  Please be aware that `out` parameters always start out as `NULL`.

Comment: @rgettman Thanks for the update. Sorry for the delay in reply, something came up. Managed to get the DBMS output from the procedure, and the output I get in JDBC is shorter than the one I get when I run it in SQLDeveloper. Thus, something is not working at that point, and we shall investigate further. Thanks very much for taking the time to help.